# How to display an image represented by R G B values separately in 3 matrices in JAVA

Tags: java, image, image-processing, rgb, grayscale

I have 3 2D matrices of the same size (let say 200 rows and 300 columns). Every matrix represent the value of one of the three "basic" color (red, green and blue). The values of the matrix can be between 0 and 255. Now I want to combine these matrices to show them as a colored image (200 by 300 pixels). How can I do it in JAVA?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First :you can create **Color** from this values like:

**`Color c = new Color(red, green, blue, alpha);`**

Note that:

1. **red** is the value of Matrics1
2. **green** is the value of Matrics2
3. **blue** is the value of Matrics3

Then create new image :

`BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(200/*Width*/, 300/*height*/, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);`

then set the value on the image Like this:

```
image.setRGB(x, y, c.getRGB());
```

This is the code for this steps ,Try it :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int red[][] = new int[200][300];
        int green[][] = new int[200][300];
        int blue[][] = new int[200][300];
        /////////////////set this matrices 

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(200/*Width*/, 300/*height*/, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 300; j++) {
                Color c = new Color(red[i][j], green[i][j], blue[i][j]);
                image.setRGB(i, j, c.getRGB());
            }
        }
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("/////////////image path.jpg"));
    }
}
```